# ASP.NET Razor pages data linking

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

So I am currently trying to create a counsellor appointment booking system using ASP.NET Razor pages. I have 2 models so far, Counsellor and Schedule which have been created as follows:
[image]

[image]

I am now trying to create a schedule for a counsellor, where the counsellor name is selected from a drop down list containing all counsellors in the database. However, when I try to create the schedule I receive an error saying I cannot insert the value NULL into column Description. So I think it is trying to create a new counsellor object when I try to create the Schedule.

Here is my index.cshtml page and my index.cshtml.cs page for the schedule model
[image]

[image]

This is my create.cshtml and create.cshtml.cs pages also for schedule model:
[image]

[image]

Lastly I show the database table designers for both counsellors and schedules:
[image]

[image]

If anyone can assist, i just want to retrieve counsellor name when creating the schedule.For some reason it is like it is trying to create a new counsellor object so it gives me an error saying i cannot enter the value into the description column.

Comment: Please add code and data as text [(using code formatting)](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#duplicate=0), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; C) are difficult to read clearly by visual impaired user and many more reasons explained with great details here. [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Check the difference. [BindProperty]

Answer (score 1):

You can find you are using `[Requeired]` on `public string Description{get;set;}` in model Counseller,and you are passing `Schedule.Counseller.Description` to OnPostAsync in Create page.So when you use
`_context.Schedule.Add(Schedule)`,it will also insert the `Counseller`,and it will get the error `cannot insert the value NULL into column Description`.

If you want to add the `Counseller` when adding the `Schedule`,you need to set default values of  Counseller `[Required]` properties.

[image]

Comment: Okay thanks I will give this a try. 
Just curious , since I am using the counsellorID to reference the counsellor table, which has I have entered data for in fields for each counsellor. Is it trying o create a new counsellor when I am trying to add the counsellor name to the schedule? Because I just wanted it use the counsellorID and then shouldn’t it know that description and other fields for that counsellor are not null since I have entered values in for those.